# display dropdown menu value in uilabel or text

Tags: swift, menu, uilabel

I have been struggling for a while now. I'm trying to create a Dropdown Menu in Xcode which I've done, but my main goal is to display something in a uilabel or something similar, for Example: I select from the menu "Apartment 1" then in UILabel it displays the price "$ 2000"

The code is as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var purchaseprice: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var btnSelectPropert: UIButton!

let transparentView = UIView()

let tableView = UITableView()

var selectedButton = UIButton()


var dataSource = [String]()


    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(CellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    
}

func addTransparentView(frames: CGRect) {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    transparentView.frame = window?.frame ?? self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(transparentView)
    
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height, width: frames.width, height: 400)
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    
    transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
    tableView.reloadData()
    let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeTransparentView))
    transparentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)
    transparentView.alpha = 0
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut,animations: {
        self.transparentView.alpha = 0.5
        self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height + 5, width: frames.width, height: CGFloat(self.dataSource.count * 50))
    }, completion: nil)


}

@objc  func removeTransparentView() {
    let frames = selectedButton.frame
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut,animations: {
        self.transparentView.alpha = 0
        self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height, width: frames.width, height: 0)
    }, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func onClickSelectProperty(_ sender: Any) {
    dataSource = ["Apartment A3","Apartment A4","Apartment A5","Apartment A6","Apartment A8","Apartment A9","Apartment A12","Apartment E1","Sectional Title 50A","Sectional Title 65A","Free Standing 70A","Free Standing 70A Core","Free Standing 85A","Free Standing 100A"]
    selectedButton = btnSelectPropert
    addTransparentView(frames: btnSelectPropert.frame)
    self.comfee.text = "N$: \(btnSelectPropert)"
}

extension CalculatorViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedButton .setTitle(dataSource[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
    removeTransparentView()
}
```

I've managed to get menu working but I don't know how to display a value in uilabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the this code in didSelectRowAt method

```
switch dataSource[indexPath.row] {
    case "Apartment A3":
        purchaseprice.text = "2000"
    case "Apartment A4":
        purchaseprice.text = "3000"
    case "Apartment A5":
        purchaseprice.text = "4000"
    case "Apartment A6":
        purchaseprice.text = "5000"
    case "Apartment A7":
        purchaseprice.text = "6000"
    default :
        break
    }
```